# Is it possible to use curly braces in vue js style segment?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I was wondering if it is possible to use curly braces for a value in the style segment in vue.js?

For example

```
.container {
  background: url({{ image-url }};
  color: {{ color-1 }}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [experimental feature](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0043-sfc-style-variables.md) to bind CSS variables provided from the script. Try this:

```
<template>
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum</div>
</template>

<script>
import {ref} from 'vue'
export default {
  setup() {
    const color = ref('red');
    const image = ref('url(https://picsum.photos/200/300)');
    
    return {color}
  }
};
</script>

<style vars="{ color, image }">
.text {
  color: var(--color);
  background-image: var(--image);
}
</style>
```

Or try new [v-bind()](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/231) injection

Comment: do you only have to return color or also image?

Comment: if you use `<script setup>`(https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html) you don't need to return anything. otherwise you have to return them.